# Map an array of functions to their return values in point-free style

Tags: javascript, programming-puzzle, functional-programming

## Introduction

I have some JavaScript code that uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map an array of functions `fns` to their return values:

```js
const fns = [() => 1, () => 2];
const result = fns.map(
  fn => fn()
);
console.log(result); // => [1, 2]
```

## Challenge

The argument to `map` above is `fn => fn()`. The challenge is to **rewrite this function using [point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)**. Your solution should work when it replaces the third line of the above program:

```js
const fns = [() => 1, () => 2];
const result = fns.map(
  /* your solution should work when inserted here */
);
console.log(result); // => [1, 2]
```

`fn => fn()` is not a valid solution because it defines a parameter named `fn`. Writing a function in point-free style requires writing it **without any variable or parameter names**.

Note that `map` will pass three arguments to your solution function: `currentValue: () => T`, `index: number`, and `array: Array<() => T>`. The function for the solution **must return the result of calling** the `currentValue` function, so hard-coding `1` and `2` will not help. The functions being mapped over are guaranteed to ignore their arguments and their `this` value, so calling the function in any way will work.

## Scoring

The **best answer** is the one that is represented by the **fewest tokens** when lexed. The [ANTLR 4 JavaScript lexer](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/cdd2a8a1cd7f08cbeef62098575a3bd2f524d5e3/javascript/JavaScriptLexer.g4) is the official lexer for the sake of objectivity, but if you know how a lexer works you should be able to estimate how many tokens some JavaScript needs without having to read that link. For example, `fn => fn()` is composed of five tokens: `fn` `=>` `fn` `(` `)`.

However, I personally think that figuring out *any* answer is the fun part, so if this problem interests you, try to solve it yourself before scrolling down and seeing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the answer by Rory O'Kane](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169898/44718):

> **10 tokens**: `Number.call.bind(String.call)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY0xDsMgFEN3TuERpJaoWaP0CF06RhkIoRHVzycC0utTWjbLfrbf5mOSjf7IVw6rK8UGThkvThgxSYXxjtsFTfTzIFoeXTopV6SCejeHFMDj3BcXtTVEevG8ymeOnre/oYRq1UBOU9hkG1ADuu63PNWPfi7lCw)

It is trivial, since `Number.call, String.call`, `Object.call`, `Function.call`, `(function () {}).call`, `Function.prototype.call` are all the same.

If [Bind Operator Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) is accepted, this could be simplified to:

> **6 tokens**: `::Function.call.call`

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAZpGBeGBtAFASmQPhgRgBoYtcYAmAXQG4AoUSWAJwFMIBXAG1hQQgDoAtgEMADulowYALmkAxdmGBQAluH7BhnThq2damOgwghOLfpxABzdKw7dDMAPROyqIhUpA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

BTW, if eval is allowed `eval("Number.call.bind(String.call)")` only use 4 tokens.

Answer (score 1):

This combination of [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) works:

```js
Function.prototype.call.call.bind(Function.prototype.call)
```

**16 tokens:** `Function` `.` `prototype` `.` `call` `.` `call` `.` `bind` `(` `Function` `.` `prototype` `.` `call` `)`

```js
const fns = [() => 1, () => 2];
const result = fns.map(
  Function.prototype.call.call.bind(Function.prototype.call)
);
console.log(result); // => [1, 2]
```

## Explanation

`Function.prototype.call` is not a solution on its own because `map` will call `call` with its `this` value set to `undefined`. `call`’s purpose is to call the function in `this`, so when `this` is `undefined` a `TypeError` is raised.

Similarly, `Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype)` is insufficient because the `call` function is called with `this` set to `Function.prototype`, and the function you want called set to the first argument. Calling `Function.prototype()` with any arguments returns `undefined`, so the function will return `undefined` instead of `1` or `2`.

My solution works by using the second `call` to make the `fn` argument the `this` of the first `call`, like this:

```
fn => Function.prototype.call.call(fn)
```

Now the first `call` can do what it is made for, calling the argument in its `this` value.